# Good references for ARIA use?

Tags: html, web-applications, accessibility, wai-aria

Does anyone have any trusted references for ARIA use? I'm looking for something to base my markup on, but can't really find that many examples from trusted sources.

Right now I'm pretty much going from the [ARIA spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) and from [this site](http://test.cita.illinois.edu/aria/states.php), but would love a couple more good references to make sure I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a really useful one I found:
http://oaa-accessibility.org/examples/role/77/

Answer (score 4):

Try http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-to-wai-aria/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/

Answer (score 2):

The guys at WebAIM are great too:

[WebAIM - ARIA](http://webaim.org/techniques/aria/)

Answer (score 1):

Derek Featherstone’s article on A List Apart is a useful read about the practicalities of ARIA.

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/aria-and-progressive-enhancement/

Answer (score 1):

This is very useful and detailed:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA